# Area51 statistics page for Islam.SE is not showing any avid users

Tags: bug, area-51

It would seem that [the Area51 statistics page for Islam Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14922/islam) is not showing any avid users:

[image: Screenshot]

I am guessing that this is a bug so I am here reporting it.

Comment: I suspect you don't have 192 questions per day either. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio no, but really, i feel like SE should keep it that way, haha :P  Everything seems to be back to normal now.